# Screenshots from multiple Xservers

Tags: xorg, x-server, screenshot, xephyr

I want to take screenshots simultaneously from multiple X servers on one desktop PC.

I have multiple users logged in different terminals (`tty1`, `tty2`, `tty3`, `tty4`) who start multiple Xservers with `startx /usr/bin/openbox-session -- :1` (and `:2`, `:3`, `:4` respectively). So I can access each one of them with `Ctrl+Alt+F8`, `+F9`, `+F10`, `+F11`.

There is only one monitor on that desktop.

I want to take screenshots for each of these X servers, preferably with `scrot`, but I currently get a black/blank image whenever I try it. Only when I am active on that X server I get a proper screenshot.

For example, if I am on `Ctrl+Alt+F8` and run `scrot test.png` I get a proper screenshot; if I understand correctly I do not have to set the `$DISPLAY`, since being on `Ctrl+Alt+F8` I get `echo $DISPLAY` > `:1`. But if I run `sleep 10; scrot test.png` and go to `Ctrl+Alt+F7`, then I get a black image.

How can I get multiple screenshots from each one of those terminals simultaneously?

What worked for me was `Xephyr`. The only problem with this solution seems to be that when I run extremely fast `xdotool` commands it is not as responsive as X.

For future reference, what I did for every of the four users and terminals was:

In `~/.profile`, I set each user to auto-login after my system boot, like:

```
if [[ -z $DISPLAY ]] && [[ $(tty) = /dev/tty1 ]]; then
     sleep 30 # for some reason it crashes if I do not let 
              # it sleep for a while, not necessarily so long. 
              # I guess it has to do with my "normal" X at DISPLAY=:0 . 
              # Thus for tty2 I let it sleep 40 seconds, 
              # for tty3 50 seconds and so on.
     startx
fi
```

In `~/.Xsession`, I start an Xserver/client (with blackbox) and Xephyr (with openbox) in it like:

```
Xephyr -fullscreen -screen 1920x1200 :11 &
exec blackbox & 
sleep 3 # Perhaps sleeping is redundant.
DISPLAY=:11 /usr/bin/openbox-session
```

I want the "final" window manager do be `openbox-session`. I would like to use `openbox` for both the Xserver and `Xephyr`, but  `exec openbox & DISPLAY=:11 /usr/bin/openbox-session` crashes, while `exec openbox & DISPLAY=:11 /usr/bin/openbox`  does not.

This way, the user in `:11` can take screenshot, while the monitor shows `:0`. (or `:13`, `:14`, etc.).

I did not try `XVnc`, but I have the feeling that it might be slower than `Xephyr`; please correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: The `$DISPLAY` variable needs to change for `scrot`. This will not happen if it remains in the subshell launched from the Xserver you just switched from.

Comment: each one of those VTs is a separate `X` server. If you are on one of them and switch to another you're looking at a different `X` server - a different `$DISPLAY`. So when you run a delayed `scrot` with one `$DISPLAY` and switch to a different one before it executes its `$DISPLAY` goes dark. It would have worked without `Xephyr` at all - and, in truth, layering the servers that way only complicates the issue further, though it can be made to work.

Comment: @mikeserv I appreciate very much your support and it seems I misunderstand something very basic. How could it work without `Xephyr`? When on the VT of `Ctrl+Alt+F8` I run `sleep 3; DISPLAY=$(echo $DISPLAY) scrot test.png` (which is the same as `sleep 3; DISPLAY=:1 scrot test.png` and within 3 seconds I switch to `Ctrl+Alt+F7` (where `$DISPLAY` is `:0`) I get a blank `test.png`.

Comment: This is the reason: the `scrot` process is a child of VT8 - its `$DISPLAY` is always `:1` - even after you switch. That is the value `export`ed into its environment by its parent shell - which you *leave behind* when you switch to VT7. Think about it this way - if there were no Xservers running at all and only the console - at boot you'd get a login prompt then a shell. If you switch to another you'll get *another* login prompt and *another* shell. Different VTs, different shells. Different VTs, different `$DISPLAY`s `scrot` gets *left behind*. Do `DISPLAY=:0 scrot test.png`.

Comment: When I am at VT8 and run `sleep 3; DISPLAY=:0 scrot test.png` and switch within 3 seconds to VT7, I get the screenshot of VT7. Is this what you mean? I want to work on VT7, and get the screenshot of VT8. Is this possible without `Xephyr`?

Comment: Yeah. So if there is *someone* currently looking at an `X` display that is viewable by you just by switching to it - say on VT1 as `$DISPLAY = :1` - and you are on VT8 and your `$DISPLAY = :8` then doing `DISPLAY=:1 scrot screen.shot` should grab an image of whatever that *someone* is doing on VT1. See?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I understand the problem in the question as follows:

- You are on a **text console tty**,
  so there is no X running on the tty where you are running the screenshot command.
- You can run **command line screenshot** commands for the X displays.
- You have **specified the X displays** for the screenshot commands, like in
  `DISPLAY=:2 scrot out.png`.
- The screen shot command does **not give you an error**

**But you get a black image as output**.

The problem could be that the X server is not painting the image into some image buffer, and the screenshot is taken from that empty buffer. But it could also be that it's a compositing window manager, like `compiz`, that is not painting. At least if you capture single windows, that could be the problem. I think it's worth trying to use a not compositing window manager, like `metacity`.

If that does not solve it, there is a completely different approach:

Run all your X servers as nested X servers on one display. Each nested X server is showing it's screen output in a window. You can then either make full screen screenshots of the nested display, or window screenshots on the main display.

As implementation of a nested X server, `Xephyr` seems to be the most current. There are also the older `Xnest` and `Xvfb`:

From [`man Xephyr`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/Xephyr):

```
 NAME
        Xephyr - X server outputting to a window on a pre-existing X display

 DESCRIPTION
        Xephyr  is a kdrive server that outputs to a window on a pre-existing "host" X dis‐
        play.  Think Xnest but with support for modern extensions  like  composite,  damage
        and randr.

        Unlike  Xnest  which is an X proxy, i.e.  limited to the capabilities of the host X
        server, Xephyr is a real X server which uses the host X server  window  as  "frame‐
        buffer" via fast SHM XImages.
```

In a similar way, Xvnc (from package vnc4server) could be used, providing access by VNC protocol additionally:

From [`Xvnc4`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/en/man1/Xvnc4.1.html):

```
 NAME
        Xvnc - the X VNC server

 DESCRIPTION
        Xvnc  is the X VNC (Virtual Network Computing) server.  It is based on a standard X
        server, but it has a "virtual" screen rather than a physical one.   X  applications
        display  themselves  on  it  as if it were a normal X display, but they can only be
        accessed via a VNC viewer - see vncviewer(1).

        So Xvnc is really two servers in one. To the applications it is an X server, and to
        the  remote  VNC  users it is a VNC server. By convention we have arranged that the
        VNC server display number will be the same as the X server  display  number,  which
        means  you  can  use eg. snoopy:2 to refer to display 2 on machine "snoopy" in both
        the X world and the VNC world.
```

(`Xvnc` is available as package `vnc4server` in Ubuntu)

Comment: the asker has specifically *not* set the `$DISPLAY` variable to other than the current VT. - see? *if I understand correctly I do not have to set the $DISPLAY, since being on Ctrl+Alt+F8 I get echo $DISPLAY > :1. But if I run sleep 10; scrot test.png and go to Ctrl+Alt+F7, then I get a black image.*

Answer (score 6):

#### Method #1 - Using xwd

You could just use the command line tool `xwd` to grab the X displays like so:

```
$ xwd -display :1 -root -out 1.xwd
```

You could loop through 1 to 4 like so:

```
$ for i in {1..4};do xwd -display :$i -root $i.xwd; done
```

**NOTE:** The resulting `.xwd` files are a special type of X Windows dump file.

```
$ file 1.xwd 
1.xwd: XWD X Window Dump image data, "xwdump", 4160x1440x24
```

You can use `xwud` to display them like so:

```
$ xwud -in 1.xwd
```

Or you can use ImageMagick's `display` command to view them:

```
$ display 1.xwd
```

#### Method #2 - Using import

You can also use ImagMagick's `import` command to do something similar:

```
$ import -window root -display :0.0 -screen /tmp/0.png
```

#### Method #3 - using scrot

Or as was suggested by @mikeserv in the comments, try setting the `$DISPLAY` so that `scrot` can find the active X display correctly:

```
$ DISPLAY=:1 scrot 1.png
```

This could be looped like so:

```
$ for i in {1..4};do DISPLAY=:$i scrot $i.png; done
```

#### References

- [Taking a Screenshot - ArchLinux Wiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Taking_a_screenshot)

Comment: @mikeserv - I was able to view the resulting xwd dump file using `display` out of ImageMagick. I don't even have access to that tool, `xwud` on F20. Querying the YUM repos to see if it's buried somewhere else 8-)

Comment: @mikeserv - found it, it's buried in this pkg: xorg-x11-apps-0:7.7-7.fc20.x86_64.

Comment: @mikeserv - yeah they do, my mistake. I ran that on F19 last night, and now I'm on F20 and didn't have that pkg installed...yet 8-). Updated the A with your info as well, thanks!

Comment: I may be missing something, but I understood the question as that the OP did try a solution like these, and got a black screen only - so I would expect that these methods do not work too? It the OP just did not set DISPLAY, he would get an error, not a black image, I think.

Comment: @VolkerSiegel - he didn't explicitly say that he did set `$DISPLAY`, also with these methods he does not need to set `$DISPLAY` since these commands take the display arg. directly. Also I 1/2 suspect that he might need to `export $DISPLAY`, so that `scrot` can pick it up. These will just sit here until he confirms all this for us.

Comment: But if the display is not set, he would get an error - I just tried: `$ DISPLAY= scrot out.png` gives me
`giblib error: Can't open X display. It *is* running, yeah?`. And he is aware of multiple displays, the point question makes not much sense it he would not try to address multiple displays for screenshots.

Comment: It's not that `$DISPLAY=` it's that it's likely set to `$DISPLAY=:1` in one scenario and something else entirely in the other. Without his info we're just conjecturing, just be patient and wait until he comes back to expand his Q.

Comment: @VolkerSiegel - no the asker provides the command : `sleep 10; scrot test.png`. That is run from a shell opened on /dev/tty7. There is no error because `$DISPLAY` *is* set - to `:7` - or whatever that `X` server is. In the ten seconds between calling `sleep` and switching to VT8, that X server went inactive - black screen. That is why I downvoted your answer - for which I'm sorry - but it further complicated the issue without correctly answering the question. This answer, however, was correct and had one fewer votes than yours. I wanted the correct info at top, so I voted on both.

Comment: Guys you are magnificent. I do not believe setting `$DISPLAY` works, but on the other hand I might be missing something. Perhaps the problem is indeed that "X server is not painting the image into some image buffer". My perception is that setting `$DISPLAY` helps in taking the screenshot when X is active on the same `$DISPLAY`, but I want to take a screenshot when it is not. The `solution` I was seeking was "like" having "virtual machines/desktops", but running on the same system, of course.