# Running more than one console X session with startx at the same time

Tags: x11, xorg, display, getty, xephyr

I have xfce running in display 0 (accessible via `Ctrl + Alt + F1`). I press `Ctrl + Alt + F2` and type `startx` (attempting to run more than one window manager at the same time) and receive the error "another session manager is already running xinit".

I have also installed `Xephyr` and ran in a bash console `startx -- /usr/bin/Xephyr :1`, but receive the same error as above except this time in an existing desktop environment.

How do I run more than one window environment at once? Preferably, I would do this within two different GeTTY's (i.e., `Ctrl + Alt + F1` takes me to my first environment, while `Ctrl + Alt + F2` takes me to my second, etc).

Answer (score 2):

```
startx -- :1
startx -- :2
startx -- :3
startx -- :4
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to start X on each virtual terminal/console specifying different display numbers.  In the [`xinit`](http://www.x.org/archive/X11R6.8.2/doc/xinit.1.html) manual, that is the `-display` option:

[`startx`](http://www.x.org/archive/X11R7.5/doc/man/man1/startx.1.html) is just a special case:

> The startx script is a front end to xinit(1) that provides a somewhat nicer user interface for running a single session of the X Window System. It is often run with no arguments.

Here are a few examples where someone uses the `-display` option to run X on multiple virtual terminals:

- [Multiple instances of X on different Virtual terminals with?](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=133634)
- [Screenshots from multiple Xservers](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/151277/screenshots-from-multiple-xservers)