# Intel video: crash after running different xorgs on different TTYs

Tags: linux, x11, drivers, tty, intel-graphics

Debian 10 x64

Linux pcname 4.19.0-11-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 4.19.146-1 (2020-09-17) x86_64 GNU/Linux

Intel Core i5-6200U

Intel HD Graphics 520

1. After being unable to run xorg with `startx` on TTY1 added `/usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d/20-intel.conf`:

```
Section "Device"
        Identifier "Configured Video Device"
        Driver "intel"
EndSection
```

2. Logged in on default TTY7 with user1 with GUI (tried lightdm and sddm with KDE5)
3. Logged in on TTY1 with user2 and run `startx`. Cinnamon runs well.
4. Switched back to TTY7 and got black screen with blinking input cursor. In case with lightdm machine hangs. I can't switch back to TTY1 and only REISUB helps. In case with sddm there was cyclically switching between TTY1 and back.

The same was with Intel Core i3-3120M (Debian 8 and 10).

Tried to set `uxa` and `blt` options with no changes. On PC with nvidia videocard everything working perfect with Debian 8 and 10.

Syslog (don't sure this strings related to my problem directly):

```
Oct  7 21:04:25 pcname systemd[1]: systemd-hostnamed.service: Succeeded.
Oct  7 21:04:25 pcname systemd[1]: session-c1.scope: Killing process 1073 (lightdm) with signal SIGTERM.
Oct  7 21:04:25 pcname systemd[1]: Stopping Session c1 of user lightdm.
Oct  7 21:04:25 pcname systemd[1]: session-c1.scope: Succeeded.
Oct  7 21:04:25 pcname systemd[1]: Stopped Session c1 of user lightdm.
Oct  7 21:04:26 pcname systemd[1]: systemd-fsckd.service: Succeeded.
Oct  7 21:04:28 pcname systemd[1]: lightdm.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
Oct  7 21:04:28 pcname systemd[1]: lightdm.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Oct  7 21:04:28 pcname systemd[1]: lightdm.service: Service RestartSec=100ms expired, scheduling restart.
Oct  7 21:04:28 pcname systemd[1]: lightdm.service: Scheduled restart job, restart counter is at 1.
Oct  7 21:04:28 pcname systemd[1]: Stopped Light Display Manager.
Oct  7 21:04:28 pcname systemd[1]: Starting Light Display Manager...
Oct  7 21:04:28 pcname systemd[1]: Started Light Display Manager.
Oct  7 21:04:30 pcname systemd[1]: lightdm.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
Oct  7 21:04:30 pcname systemd[1]: lightdm.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Oct  7 21:04:30 pcname systemd[1]: lightdm.service: Service RestartSec=100ms expired, scheduling restart.
Oct  7 21:04:30 pcname systemd[1]: lightdm.service: Scheduled restart job, restart counter is at 2.
Oct  7 21:04:30 pcname systemd[1]: Stopped Light Display Manager.
Oct  7 21:04:30 pcname systemd[1]: Starting Light Display Manager...
Oct  7 21:04:30 pcname systemd[1]: Started Light Display Manager.
Oct  7 21:04:33 pcname systemd[1]: lightdm.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
Oct  7 21:04:33 pcname systemd[1]: lightdm.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Oct  7 21:04:33 pcname systemd[1]: lightdm.service: Service RestartSec=100ms expired, scheduling restart.
Oct  7 21:04:33 pcname systemd[1]: lightdm.service: Scheduled restart job, restart counter is at 3.
```

What can be done to run different xorgs on different TTYs and switching between them?

Comment: Hi! What commands do you use to run xorg? Do you specify different display numbers? https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/240093/running-more-than-one-console-x-session-with-startx-at-the-same-time

Comment: `startx`. And `/home/user2/.xinitrc` with `exec cinnamon-session` in it. I does not specify different display numbers. Should I and how?

Answer (score 0):

To get a stable Intel driver I created `/etc/X11/xorg.conf.d/20-intel.conf` and defined:

```
Section "Device"
   Identifier  "Intel Graphics"
   Driver      "intel"
   Option      "AccelMethod" "sna"
   Option      "TearFree"    "true"
EndSection
```

Depending on your hardware the accel method could be "uxa" but I doubt it. (Old GPUs only)
Before setting this, I had problems with LightDM, it crashed constantly.

In /etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf I configured the greeter:

```
[Seat:*]
greeter-session=lightdm-gtk-greeter
greeter-hide-users=false
session-wrapper=/etc/lightdm/Xsession
```

In the same directory the file `lightdm-gtk-greeter.conf` is needed. It should contain: (or any other theme)

```
[greeter]
theme-name = Adwaita-dark
icon-theme-name = Adwaita
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I've edited configs right like you write, but it does not help. And I have not `/etc/lightdm/Xsession`, so tried default option.

Comment: Xsession might be crucial - but this is something which is solved differently on each distro. I've taken it from my arch linux session. But I'll look into another device, which has debian running. BTW- what do mean by "running different Xorgs" There is only one ;-)

Comment: I mean run to independent copies on tty1 and tty7. In debian there is default option `session-wrapper=lightdm-session` in `session-wrapper=lightdm-session`. And there are some [Xsession files in packages](https://packages.debian.org/search?suite=stable&section=all&arch=any&searchon=contents&keywords=Xsession). Should I try another Xsession, for example, from sddm?